# Add certificate to Mirth Keystore

Tags: java, ssl, mirth

This seems like it should be a simple thing to do. I'd like to be able to trust certs coming from services Mirth depends on without modifying the global Java cert store (or dropping a few grand per instance for the SSL plugin). I've tried the following:

#### Generate my own keystore:

Keytool commands:

```
keytool -genkey -keystore appdata\my.jks -storetype PKCS12 -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -storepass xxxxxxxx
keytool -importcert -alias my-ca-cert -file myCaCert.pem -keystore appdata\my.jks -trustcacerts -storepass xxxxxxxx
keytool -importcert -alias my-server-cert -file myServerCert.pem -keystore appdata\my.jks -trustcacerts -storepass xxxxxxxx
```

Mirth.properties:

```
keystore.path = ${dir.appdata}/my.jks
keystore.storepass = xxxxxxxx
keystore.keypass = xxxxxxxx
keystore.type = pkcs12
```

In this instance Mirth completely fails to start. First error from the log is

```
java.io.IOException: Invalid keystore format
  at com.sun.crypto.provider.JceKeyStore.engineLoad(JceKeyStore.java:724)
  at java.security.KeyStore.load(Unknown Source)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.MirthWebServer.createSSLConnector(MirthWebServer.java:370)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.MirthWebServer.<init>(MirthWebServer.java:150)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth.startWebServer(Mirth.java:385)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth.startup(Mirth.java:265)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.Mirth.run(Mirth.java:154)
```

#### Update Mirth built-in keystore:

Keytool commands:

```
keytool -importcert -alias my-ca-cert -file myCaCert.pem -keystore appdata\keystore.jks -trustcacerts -storetype jceks -storepass xxxxxxxx
keytool -importcert -alias my-server-cert -file myServerCert.pem -keystore appdata\keystore.jks -trustcacerts -storetype jceks -storepass xxxxxxxx
```

Mirth.properties:

```
keystore.path = ${dir.appdata}/keystore.jks
keystore.storepass = xxxxxxxx
keystore.keypass = xxxxxxxx
keystore.type = JCEKS
```

In this instance Mirth completely starts but the server certs are not considered valid. Error log is

```
DETAILS:    JavaException: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
  at 69352923-b68f-4e96-95a3-ad7681a7f3c1_Deploy:112 (doScript)
  at 69352923-b68f-4e96-95a3-ad7681a7f3c1_Deploy:118
  at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil.executeScript(JavaScriptUtil.java:547)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptUtil$2.doCall(JavaScriptUtil.java:379)
  at com.mirth.connect.server.util.javascript.JavaScriptTask.call(JavaScriptTask.java:113)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

#### Update the Java global keystore

Keytool commands:

```
keytool.exe -importcert -alias my-ca-cert -file myCaCert.pem -keystore cacerts -storepass xxxxxxxx
keytool.exe -importcert -alias my-server-cert -file myServerCert.pem -keystore cacerts -storepass xxxxxxxx
```

Mirth.properties: (same as above)

```
keystore.path = ${dir.appdata}/keystore.jks
keystore.storepass = xxxxxxxx
keystore.keypass = xxxxxxxx
keystore.type = JCEKS
```

This works but is not desirable because it complicates deployments (we have no control over customer environment), and I'm not confident that Java upgrades wouldn't simply overwrite the store.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Through *way* too much trial and error here's what I was able to learn:

1. Native Mirth senders/receivers themselves use the **Mirth** Keystore defined in Mirth.properties. Importing certs as described above will work for these channels.
2. If you're using the Rhino engine (e.g. Java/JavaScript) to send/receive http requests, the Mirth keystore is ignored and the global **Java** store is used. Again, the process described above works. Since my certs come from Windows it turns out I was able to simplify a bit by adding `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStoreType=WINDOWS-ROOT` to Mirth.properties and not have my field techs futzing around with Java's keytool

The reason I didn't see the Mirth channels working initially is because my channel's deploy script obtains an access token from an auth provider, and I didn't think to test the channel sender independently. I did not think it would matter whether I was doing things programmatically or configuring channels through the UI, but, well, that's Mirth for you. :/

Anyway, hopefully this will help someone, someday.

Comment: In general java keystores store private keypairs, and truststores store public keys that you trust.

Open source mirth uses the keystore in mirth.properties for the server certificate for the web server admin tools and Client API, and also if you have channel level encryption enabled.

The java truststore is where you add public certs for Certificate Authorities or self-signed certs.

Comment: I have spent hours battling to get mirth HTTP senders to accept a self signed cert, this was what I needed. Thank you so much!